# how to check the parent div, from click event on the page from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to check if I am clicking inside the div with classname as 'myclass' (in any child inside the div ). 
this code is returns only the current control in which we click , I want to check its all parents , if it has div with classname 'myclass'

```
$("body").click(function (e) {
    if (e.target.className !== "myclass") {
        doo();
    }
    alert(e.target.id);
    alert(e.target.className);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("body").click(function (e) {
   var elem = $('.myClass'); 
   if ((!elem.is(e.target)) && (elem.has(e.target).length === 0)) { 
       doo(); 
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this [SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4nxbxkgp/)

```
$('div').on('click',function(){
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    if( $parent.hasClass('myClass') ){
        alert( $(this).text() );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use closest to find the parent which is having `myclass`

try this

```
$("body").click(function (e) {
    if($(e.target).closest('.myclass').length == 0 && $(e.target).attr('class') != "myclass"){
        doo();
    }
});
```